# Record is added 3 times in asp.net action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have 2 models, one for `Poll` and for `PollOption`. In the create action, I want to add 1 `Poll` to the database and a list of `PollOption`s as well.

When I submit the form, 3 polls are added, 1 contains the correct value and 2 are empty. The poll options are added correctly but with the incorrect `Poll` foreign key (they have the foreign id of the empty poll records).

Models:

```
public class Poll
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Question { get; set; } = "";
}

public class PollOption
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Option { get; set; } = "";

    [Required]
    public int PollId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PollId")]
    [ValidateNever]
    public Poll Poll { get; set; } = new Poll();
}
```

View model:

```
public class PollVM
{
    public Poll Poll { get; set; } = new Poll();

    [ValidateNever]
    public IEnumerable<PollOption> PollOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create(PollVM pollVM) 
{
    _unitOfWork.Poll.Add(pollVM.Poll);

    foreach (var option in pollVM.PollOptions)
    {
        _unitOfWork.PollOption.Add(option);
    }

    _unitOfWork.Save();

    return View(pollVM);
}
```

View:

```
@model PollVM
<div class="index-container">
    <div class="subcontainer">
        <h1 class="title">Poll Creator</h1>
        <h2 class="subtitle">Complete the form below to create your poll!</h2>
        <form method="POST">
            <input asp-for="Poll.Id" hidden />
            <div class="form-container">
                <div class="form-input">
                    <label asp-for="Poll.Question">Question:</label>
                    <input asp-for="Poll.Question" type="text" placeholder="Type the poll question here" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-input">
                    <div class="form-input form-options">
                        <label>Answer Options:</label>
                        <div class="form-option">
                            <input name="PollOptions[0].Id" hidden>
                            <input name="PollOptions[0].Option" type="text" placeholder="Option 1" required>
                            <img src="~/images/icons/cross.svg" alt="remove-option" width="30px" class="remove-option" onclick="removeOption(this)">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-option">
                            <input name="PollOptions[1].Id" hidden>
                            <input name="PollOptions[1].Option" type="text" placeholder="Option 2" required>
                            <img src="~/images/icons/cross.svg" alt="remove-option" width="30px" class="remove-option" onclick="removeOption(this)">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="button side-button icon-button">Add Option <img src="~/images/icons/plus.svg" alt="add-option" width="25px"></button>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="button submit-button">Create!</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="~/js/answer-options.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

If I remove the poll option "add" functions, the action works correctly and only adds 1  poll which is what I want but I want it to add the poll options as well.

Comment: What is your `_unitOfWork`?

Comment: `public IEnumerable<PollOption> PollOptions { get; set; }` <-- This needs to be `List<PollOption>`, not `IEnumerable<>`. Last time I checked, ASP.NET can't bind POSTed form-data to interface types, only concrete types (unless something's changed recently?)

Comment: Also, you (generally) shouldn't be using EF entity types as model-types bound by POST requests -  - I suspect that's part of your problem.

Comment: `<form method="POST">` <-- you should use the `asp-action=""` tag-helpers to ensure consistent behaviour whereever the `<form>` is located in your website.

Comment: `<input name="PollOptions[0].Id" hidden>` <-- You're misusing `hidden` here - your HTML should be `<input type="hidden" name="PollOptions[0].Id" />` -  or better yet: `<input type="hidden" asp-for="PollOptions[0]" />`

Comment: Never assign default value for non-collection navigation property:  remove that `= new Poll();` [Reference navigations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/navigations#reference-navigations) - *Reference navigations should not be automatically initialized to a non-null default value*

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was the default value assigned for Poll in the PollOption model.